# Why the process is still running in the background?

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I've made a script that embed a pygame window into a tkinter window but when i try to quit it keeps giving me this error:

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Luca\Desktop\prova.py", line 39, in <module>
root.update()
File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1305, in update
self.tk.call('update')
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "update" command: application has been destroyed
```

this is the code:

```
import pygame
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import os
import sys

root = tk.Tk()

embed = tk.Frame(root, width = 500, height = 500) #creates embed frame for pygame window
# embed.grid(columnspan = (600), rowspan = 500) # Adds grid
embed.pack(side = TOP) #packs window to the left

buttonwin = tk.Frame(root, width = 75, height = 500)
buttonwin.pack(side = BOTTOM)

os.environ['SDL_WINDOWID'] = str(embed.winfo_id())
os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'windib'

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

pygame.display.init()
pygame.display.update()

def update():
    screen.fill(pygame.Color(255,255,255))
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0,0,0), (250,250), 125)
    pygame.display.update()
    # root.update()
    # button1 = Button(buttonwin,text = 'Draw',  command=draw)
    # button1.pack(side=LEFT)

run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    root.update()
    update()  

root.quit()
root.destroy()
pygame.quit()
```

I've also tried using sys.exit() but the script is still running in the background

Comment: ***"is still running "***: Add a `break` right after `run = False`

Comment: `break` will only break out the for loop, not the while loop.  So `root.update()` will still be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the while loop by a function and use `after` to execute it periodically:

```
def run():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            return
    update()
    root.after(100, run)

run()
root.mainloop()
pygame.quit()
```